# Getting error "command not found: fastlane"

Tags: ios, fastlane

I have tried following few tutorials but getting the same error every time.

I tried installing using bundle methods:

`bundle init` (in project repository)

I added `gem "fastlane"` in Gemfile and then used `bundle install` to install fastlane.

But when I `fastlane init` raises an error `zsh: command not found: fastlane`

[following tutorial **=**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jz-Ywxki0U)

Answer (score 2):

Try
`export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` in your shell.

If it works, add it to the `.zshrc` to make it permanent.
`source .zshrc` again in the same session or restart the shell (e.g., restart the terminal).

============= **EDIT** =============

*Substitute `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` with `export PATH="/usr/local/bin/fastlane"` if `~/.fastlane` does not exist and `/usr/local/bin/fastlane` does.
If `cd ~/.fastlane` works, proceed with `$HOME/.fastlane/bin`, and if it doesn't & `ls /usr/local/bin | grep fastlane` finds `fastlane`, substitute with `/usr/local/bin/fastlane`.*

The `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` part should be typed directly into the shell command line, i.e., the console you typed `bundle init` in.

If this solves your problem, then add the line `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` to the end of your `.zshrc` file. This file can be found in your home directory `~`.
In the terminal, `cd ~` and list all the files in the directory by `ls -al`. If you see `.zshrc`, open it with an editor of your choice, e.g., `nano` if you are new to command line tools, `vim`, `pico`, etc.
At the end of the file, add

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"
```

If `.zshrc` does not exist, create one under your home directory and add the above line (Then your single-line `.zshrc` will only contain the above command.).

Comment: thanks @Jay, but I'm not familier about the shell term you used, can you please mention in more details, where I need to add this line of code ?